# How to prevent a new controller from creating a new folder for its views in the Views folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm writing an `ASP.NET MVC 5` application, where folders are organized by *feature* (`ViewModels`, `Controllers`, and `Views` are grouped together). I was able to override all default folder paths and manage all routing successfully. However, every time I create a new controller, `Visual Studio` creates a new `Views` folder and a child folder with controller name, which is a little bit annoying but that's fine.

Now, when I create another controller, I'm getting this error, because Visual Studio created the Views folder *again*, which is hidden now (excluded from the project). To fix this, I have to include the Views folder in the project and delete it after I create the controller.

Does anybody know any way to prevent this?

> Error
>
> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'A file or
>   folder with the name 'Views' already exists on disk at this location.
>   Please choose another name.
>
> If this file or folder does not appear in the Solution Explorer, then
>   it is not currently part of your project. To view files which exist on
>   disk, but are not in the project, select Show All Files from the
>   Project menu.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using visual studio's `Add` -> `Controller` which generates the undesired view folder, create your controller using `Add` -> `Class`. Name the class conventionally with a `Controller` suffix and subclass `Controller` like this `MyController : Controller`.

Comment: Thank you, Issac. That is what I've been doing and it works fine, just little bit tedious.

Comment: does anyone know if this can be done on visual studio 2015 with the settings or selecting a type of controller?

Comment: The folders get generated for me sometimes after the controllers have been existing for awhile. I'm not sure if Visual Studio is creating them or if they are getting created when debugging. I'm guessing the former. I'll have to do some testing on it I guess, but we are about to move to MVC 6, and I'm not sure if the problem will still exist there.